# Regex in VBA - How to resume the search?

Tags: javascript, regex, excel, vba

Good day to you all.

I have a issue with VBA and its implementation of regex.

In Javascript, when I use the Execute method several times, the engine resumes where it stopped.

The following example:

```java
<script>
var subject = '?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?';
var regex = /\?[^\?]+\?|({[^}]+})/g;
var match

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
match = regex.exec(subject)
console.log(match)
}
</script>
```

Returns

```
["?{testtag}?", undefined, index: 0, input: "?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?"]
["{4065}", "{4065}", index: 12, input: "?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?"]
["?{testtag}?", undefined, index: 18, input: "?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?"]
null
["?{testtag}?", undefined, index: 0, input: "?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?"]
["{4065}", "{4065}", index: 12, input: "?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?"]
["?{testtag}?", undefined, index: 18, input: "?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?"]
null
["?{testtag}?", undefined, index: 0, input: "?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?"]
["{4065}", "{4065}", index: 12, input: "?{testtag}?+{4065}?{testtag}?"]
```

As you can see, the engine resumes just after the match.

The same thing in VBA:

```
Sub test_regex()

    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim source_string As String

    source_string = "?{testtag}?+{4065}+?{testtag}?"

        With regEx
            .pattern = "\?[^\?]+\?|({[^}]+})"
        End With

        For i = 1 To 10
            Set matches = regEx.Execute(source_string)
             Debug.Print (matches(0))
        Next
End Sub
```

Returns

```
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
?{testtag}?
```

The 0th element is the only one in the array. It appears that the engine starts over at the beginning of the string, on each call.

Is there any way I can get VBA to behave like JS?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the VBScript RegExp object requires you to explicitly set the `Global` flag with a boolean value, also the `.Execute()` method returns a collection of matches, you just need to iterate over each one:

```
Sub MM_Demo()

    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim source_string As String

    source_string = "?{testtag}?+{4065}+?{testtag}?"

    With regEx
        .Pattern = "\?[^\?]+\?|({[^}]+})"
        .Global = True    '// <~~ global flag
    End With

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(source_string)

    '// I'm going for a For Each loop, but it's down to preference
    For Each Match In matches
        Debug.Print CStr(Match)
    Next

End Sub
```

which will output:

```
?{testtag}?
{4065}
?{testtag}?
```

---

There's also a `.SubMatches` collection that you can access if you have set up your pattern in such a way. For example:

```
For Each subMatch In matches(0).SubMatches
    Debug.Print CStr(subMatch)
Next
```

Comment: OP is already early-binding.. I'd recommend using the actual early-bound types instead of working with `Object`. But the key point was that `Global` flag. And a `For Each` loop.

Comment: My bad - I used late binding on my machine rather than setting a reference, I'll update the code!

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I did not set the global flag to 'true' on purpose.
I want to implement the [best regex trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) , and the method requires getting the matches one after an other, the way the JS does it.

Comment: @MaximeVisconte but your javascript version **does** set the global flag (it has `/g` at the end), without that flag the parser will stop at the first match each time. Also the 'trick' will use more resources by executing that match with each loop - you only have to do it once and iterate over a collection which is faster, and makes more sense.

Comment: There is still a difference with ou without the flag.

Output JS with the /g:
     "?{testtag}?"
JS without the /g:
     "?{testtag}?"

VBA with the .Global=True:
?{testtag}?
{4065}
?{testtag}?

VBA with nothing or .Global = False:
?{testtag}?

The thing, I believe, is linked on how the regex object works.
Indeed, as shown in my first post, if I make the same call over and over in VBA, I get the same result.

In JS, the result is different. 

I would like to reproduce such a behavior.

Thanks for your time

Comment: @MaximeVisconte The VBScript Regex engine and the Javascript regex engine are two completely different engines and languages entirely so trying to replicate the behaviour in this case isn't going to work. The VBScript engine simply doesn't work that way.